# Recovering planar wave from Huygens principle

Tags: optics, huygens-principle, plane-wave

I am trying to get a basic understanding of the Huygens principle, by checking whether a planar wave is the same as what is calculated from the principle when the wave reaches a screen.

```
 x       screen
 ^         ^
 |         |
 |    L    |
-|---------O--->z
 |         |
 |         |
```

If checking the wave reaching $O$, from Huygens principle, I get

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i(k\sqrt{L^2+x^2}-\omega t)}}{\sqrt{L^2+x^2}}\left(1+\frac{L}{\sqrt{L^2+x^2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

where $\left(1+\frac{L}{\sqrt{L^2+x^2}}\right)$ is the obliquity factor.

If I understand correctly the above integral should be equal to $e^{i(kL-\omega t)}$, but how to get this quantity?

Comment: In https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660944/interpretation-fourier-diffraction/660957#660957 almost the same integral is discussed with a sign difference in the obliquity factor. I think the (-) is correct not (+) for the obliquity factor should be less than 1, otherwise asymptotically the two are the same.

Comment: @hyportnex There is usually a 1/2 in the factor but I omitted that.