# In diffraction, what exactly is causing the obliquity factor?

Tags: diffraction, huygens-principle

As I understand it, this is a factor we introduce (sometimes as $\cos\theta$, sometimes as $\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos\theta)$) to correct behaviour at an aperture when Huygens principle is applied (e.g. prevent backwards propagation). This matches observation.

From Goodman's *Introduction to Fourier Optics*:

> The last property, namely the obliquity factor, has no simple
> "quasi-physical" ex- planation, but arises in slightly different forms
> in all the theories of diffraction. It is perhaps expecting too much
> to find such an explanation. After all, there are no material sources
> within the aperture; rather, they all lie on the rim of the aperture.
> Therefore the Huygens-Fresnel principle should be regarded as a
> relatively simple mathematical construct that allows us to solve
> diffraction problems without paying attention to the **physical details
> of exactly what is happening at the edges of the aperture.**

It is the part in bold that I am trying to understand / pay attention to.

[image]

Blindly applying "every point of a wavefront *acts as* a spherical emitter", it is not clear to me what is happening at the edges of the aperture that is causing this fall-off in amplitude. I suppose the Goodman quote suggests there isn't an 'easy' reason / intuition, but could someone point me towards *some* reason?

Would appreciate this a lot!

Comment: "can be derived mathemtically" may not be true??

Comment: @user45664 ah right, my bad! Even better question then!

Comment: K. 622 Where did the image come from? I was wondering if there is an actual photo that had those blurry areas that spread out at different angles. Or is this just a created image.

Comment: it is not trivial to derive the *obliquity* factor but it is done [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660944/interpretation-fourier-diffraction/660957#660957) in some detail for paraxial waves, it is more complicated for the general case.

Comment: @BillAlsept just Wikipedia (article on diffraction)

Comment: @hyportnex thanks; I guess my question is; assuming Huygens principle, which says every point in that aperture should act as a spherical emitter, what is happening at the edge of the aperture that is causing those spherical emitters to have amplitudes that taper to 0 (with 0 being precisely at the edge)?

Comment: If you insist on assuming that the wave propagation follows Huygens's original idea *strictly* so that every point of the wave front is a uniform source of spherical wavelets then you do not need anything else at the edge. The *blockage* by the screen itself will get you diffraction, and this is just a pure Fourier transform of the aperture field. But then what to do with the non-physicality of the backward part of the sphere, this is what the obliquity factor is for according which to the secondary wavelets emitted by each point of the wave front ....

Comment: .... are not really uniformly spherical but have a directional amplitude. This directionality is the *obliquity* factor that I derived in one form. When it is $\cos\phi$ then sideways at $\phi=\pm \pi/2$ the amplitude is zero, but backwards is still $-1$. With another page of more complicated derivation that is not the 1st order *paraxial* approximation, you  can get to $\tfrac12(1+\cos\phi)$ that is zero when $\phi=\pi$, as desired for backward propagation, but only $\tfrac12$ sideways, so the edge is slightly and somewhat more smoothly restricts the aperture field, but Fourier T is dominant.

Comment: The obliquity factor does not taper the total *sideways* field zero, the aperture blockage does that with or without the obliquity factor. The obliquity factor explains why you do not have backward wave propagation within the Huygens principle that otherwise would assume spherical wavelets at every point of the front propagating uniformly in all directions, which we do not see.

Answer (score 0):

The obliquity factor is not needed to eliminate the backward wave.  See my

Huygens' Principle geometric derivation and elimination of the wake and backward wave

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-99049-7

Especially see the Notes in the Supplementary Information (SI). The backward wave is eliminated by an additional backward wave of opposite polarity (or sign) under the proper conditions.  Eg. 'As for the backward wave, a source propagates both a forward wave and a backward wave when it is stationary, but it propagates only the forward wave front when it is advancing with a speed equal to the propagation speed of the wave fronts'. Think of an impulsively excited planar source.