# Huygens Light Theory using Spheres and Miller's recent discovery?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, huygens-principle

Huygens writes in "Treatise on Light" a theory that propagation of light through the aether can be explained using Spherical waves emanating from every point and they interfere.  Miller [writes](https://www-ee.stanford.edu/%7Edabm/146.pdf) recently that he has fixed Huygens theory to explain some principles of diffraction, adding a backward component to the theory.

I'm trying to understand the below except.  Does point A create an initial sphere, then subsequently every point on that sphere joins with another point on the sphere to create new smaller spheres?  Also, polarization: is a dipole established?  I think Miller adds this to the theory.

[image]

ref: copyright expired, Huygens treatise on light

Comment: Longitudinal acoustic waves also follow Helmholtz's equation from which Kirchhoff and similar integral representations, Sommerfeld,  Runge, Debye, etc., follow. They all try to find physical and mathematical justification to Fresnel's obliquity factor and to the mathematically contradictory boundary conditions *on* the screen. It is amazing that Kirchhoff's original is about as good as the approximation ever gets in practice and then you might as well just use Duffieux's Fourier transform https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660944/interpretation-fourier-diffraction/660957#660957.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does point A create an initial sphere

Just to be slightly rigorous with the definitions: Point A is a point source, and the wavefront that forms from it will be shaped as a sphere, due to the point source and the geometry that Huygens established.

> Then subsequently every point on that sphere joins with another point on the sphere to create new smaller spheres?

That depends on what you mean by "every point on that sphere". Huygens' description is that of a propagating wavefront, meaning that the wavefront is described at a time $t + \Delta t$. This means that the sphere at a time $t + \Delta t$ will not be the same as described at time $t + \Delta t= 0$, but rather the sphere will be "larger" (as the wavefront propagates in free space).

At every point of the initial sphere at time $t + \Delta t= 0$, you can model it as an infinite distribution of point-like sources that at time $t + \Delta t \neq 0$ are the sources of secondary wavelets, that move at the same speed $v$ of propagation in all directions:

[image: From this island universe: https://thisislanduniverse.com/2023/08/15/spherical-wavefronts-cosmological-reality/]

If you were to take a tangential cut of the surface of all these secondary wavelets, you would form the **envelope** of the wavefront at time $t + \Delta t$.

What you have there is a 2D representation of a 3D problem, but you can clearly see the envelope (as DCF, flattened in only 2 dimensions) so you can see the wavelets (smaller sources) and how the wavefront is formed.

> Also, polarization: is a dipole established? I think Miller adds this to the theory.

This was never treated by Huygens, as his description predates even Maxwell and any other form of all-encompassing electromagnetic description of the phenomenon. I don't have access to the original postulate by Huygens but none of the material I reviewed references to dipoles.

As for polarization in Miller's paper, I would not go as far as to state that the polarization is taken into account, while I think that treatment would also require to talk about material properties of the propagation, but in my opinion Miller's paper does not reach that far and is rather a complement of what Huygens establishes for the source of the illumination, rather than a proper treatment of the polarization state of the dipoles or any other interactions that would lead to the polarization. Maybe you are right that the treatment may be somewhat reworked to add polarization based on Miller's correction, but it is not explicit in his paper from my perspective.