# How can the amplitude of the secondary waves be derived by Huygens principle?

Tags: optics, huygens-principle

#### Huygens principle

The **Huygens principle** states that every point on a wavefront of a spherical wave
$$
A(\vec{r},t) = \frac{A_0}{r}e^{i(kr-\omega t)}
$$
can be seen as the source of a spherical wavelet. I tried to understand this quantitatively, by deriving the amplitude $B_0$ of the secondary waves.

#### My Derivation

[image: Valid XHTML].

Suppose the source of the primary wave is located at the $P_0$. The amplitude of the primary wave at point $Q$ a distance $r_0$ away from the source is given by:
$$
A(Q,t) = \frac{A_0}{r_0}e^{i(kr_0-\omega t)}
$$
Now Huygens principle says that every point $Q$ on this spherical surface is the source of a secondary (spherical) wave:
$$
B(\vec{s},t) = \frac{B_0}{s}e^{i(ks-\omega t)}
$$
It follows that the amplitude $C(P,t)$ at a point $P$ at distance $z=\overline{P_0P}$ from the primary source is the sum (or rather the integral) of all secondary waves created at the surface $S$ of the sphere with radius $r_0$:
$$
C(P,t) = \int_S B(\vec{s},t) \,\text{d}S \\
$$
$$
C(P,t) = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{B_0}{s}e^{i(ks-\omega t)} \,r_0^2\sin\theta\,\text{d}\theta\,\text{d}\varphi \\
$$

If we denote the angle $\theta=\angle QP_0P$, the law of cosines states that
$$
s = \sqrt{r_0^2+z^2-2r_0z\cos\theta}
$$
We can therefore substitute
$$
\text{d}s = \frac{r_0z}{s}\sin\theta\,\text{d}\theta
$$
into the integral above and obtain:
$$
C(P,t)=2\pi r_0^2 B_0e^{-\omega t}\cdot\frac{1}{r_0z}\int_{z-r_0}^{z+r_0} e^{iks} \text{d}s
$$
And after solving and simplifying we get:
$$
C(P,t) = 4\pi r_0^2 \,B_0\,\frac{e^{i(kz-\omega t)}}{z}\,\frac{\sin(kr_0)}{kr_0}
$$
On the other hand, if we hadn't used Huygens principle, the amplitude at $P$ would just be the value of the primary wave at that point:
$$
C(P,t) = A_0 \frac{e^{i(kz-\omega t)}}{z}
$$
Comparing the two equations makes it clear that the amplitude of the secondary waves must be:
$$
B_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi r_0^2}\frac{kr_0}{\sin(kr_0)} A_0 = -\frac{i}{\lambda}\frac{A_0}{r_0}e^{ikr_0}\cdot\frac{1}{1-e^{2ikr_0}}
$$

#### Correct Solution

However, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle#Mathematical_expression_of_the_principle), the amplitude of the secondary waves is:
$$
B_0 = -\frac{i}{\lambda}\,A(Q,t)\,K(\chi) = -\frac{i}{\lambda}\frac{A_0}{r_0}e^{ikr_0}\cdot K(\chi)
$$
with an inclination factor $K(\chi)$, and $\chi$ being the angle in the diagram above:
$$
\cos\chi = \frac{z\cos\theta-r_0}{\sqrt{r_0^2+z^2-2r_0z\cos\theta}}=\frac{z\cos\theta-r_0}{s}
$$
So the inclination factor depends on the angle $\theta$, but I have no idea why it is necessary.

#### Questions

My questions are:

1. Where does the inclination factor $K(\chi)$ come from?
2. What is wrong with my derivation?
3. What is the correct derivation of the amplitude $B_0$ of the secondary waves, using the inclination factor?

Comment: A $K(\chi)$ is needed such that $K(\pi)=0$ otherwise there is a backward propagation that is not observed. Here is a derivation of *an* obliquity factor (it is not unique, there are several possible factors having essentially the same asymptotic behavior) https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660944/interpretation-fourier-diffraction/660957#660957